# Embedding Album Art While Ripping

Tags: ubuntu-one, cd-ripping

Ubuntu One just released an update to the music app for Android and it says that it will now show embedded album art.  I'd like to try this out, but I can't figure out how to embed the album art while ripping the cd.  I use Sound Juicer, is there anyway to get this to work?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if soundjuicer can do it, but if not, I suggest using musicbrainz picard (which is in Ubuntu,) to embed the album art *after* ripping. Picard is mainly for fixing the music metadata by looking up the files on musicbrainz.org, but you can enable a switch to download and embed album art, I believe from Amazon. Note that this will work if you ripped the files to mp3, but not for ogg files, as there is no standard way to embed album arts in ogg files, afaik.

Comment: According to the ogg FAQ it was designed for that from the start, and I've managed to find some apps that say they'll do it, but I don't know yet if Ubuntu One will recognize it.